# Undestanding the image view parameter compatibility requirements

Tags: vulkan

I am having some troubles understanding the *Image and image view parameter compatibility requirements* table in the [`VkImageViewCreateInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkImageViewCreateInfo.html) documentation and the `VkImageViewCreateInfo::viewType`. The image `VkImageViewCreateInfo` properties seams to be flexible enough to create, for example, a single 1D or 1D array image view of a 2D image. I tried to create 1D image view out of a 2D image with validation layers enabled and I got no warnings (I don't know exactly which row/column will be used if this is a valid usage).

Is it true to assume that there is one-to-one mapping between the `VkImageCreateInfo::imageType` + `VkImageCreateInfo::arrayLayers` in the image and the `VkImageViewCreateInfo::viewType` in the view, i.e. this [VkImageViewType](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkImageViewType.html) type is there to handle the special case of cube maps, otherwise `viewType` could've been inferred from the image type? If not, how does the 1D view of 2D image work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a 1D view of a 2D image, only the combinations listed in the table are valid.

It looks like the page you're looking at hasn't been regenerated recently, or doesn't include modifications made by the VK_KHR_maintenance1 extension.

Ignoring that extension and cubemaps for now, it's not quite true that there is a 1:1 correspondence between imageType+arrayLayers and viewType. A 2D image with multiple layers can be used with either 2D or 2D_ARRAY view types, and a 2D image with only one layer can still be used with a 2D_ARRAY view type. The view type corresponds to the SPIR-V resource types, and mostly determines how many coordinates are needed to identify a location in the view.

Then there is the cubemap complication, as you observed.

With VK_KHR_maintenance1, you can create 2D and 2D_ARRAY views of a subset of the slices in a 3D image. The extension adds two new rows to the table to describe that case.